# Is the limit $\lim_{x \to 1}{(2-x)}^{\tan(\pi/2)x}$ undefined?

Tags: limits

I'm preparing for a calculus exam and came across this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 1}{(2-x)}^{\tan(\pi/2)x}$$

Of course $\tan(\pi/2)$ is undefined, but the excercise was a multiple choice with options $\infty$, 0, e, $e^\pi$ and $e^{2/\pi}$

So WolframAlpha says $\tan(\pi/2)$ is $\infty$, I figured this is a $1^\infty$ indeterminate and first tried to rewrite it like this:

$$
\lim_{x \to 1}{(1+(1-x))}^{(1-x)^{-1}(1-x)\tan(\pi/2)x}
$$

And I have $$\lim_{x \to 1}{(1+(1-x))}^{(1-x)^{-1}}=e$$

But then I got stuck trying to calculate $$\lim_{x \to 1}(1-x)\tan(\pi/2)x$$

I've also tried other methods but everything I try I end up stuck in a similar situation. Also, all the ways I can think of to calculate this limit seem too far-fetched (including the one above).

So, is the excercise wrong? If it's undefined, is it because of $\tan(\pi/2)$ or is there some other argument?

Comment: $$\tan \bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{2}x\bigr) = \cot \bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{2}(1-x)\bigr)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it says $\tan(\pi/2)x$, it's meant to be interpreted as $\tan((\pi/2)x)$, not $(\tan(\pi/2))x$ (yes, it is terrible notation).  So the expression $(x-1)\tan((\pi/2)x)$ is a $0\cdot\infty$ indeterminate form as $x\to 1$ and you can try using L'Hopital's rule.  If it were $(\tan(\pi/2))x$, the expression would of course be undefined for all values of $x$, and so it would be meaningless to talk about the limit.

(If this confusion is not what you are actually asking about, apologies and I will delete this answer!)

Comment: Oh, that explains it. I had never seen that before. Then again, I'm pretty new to all this. Thanks!

Comment: @gnp Probably you had never seen this before because few people would write $\tan(\pi/2)x$ when they really mean $\tan((\pi/2)x)$. It would be fair to say that the problem was _written incorrectly,_ but we make our best guess as to what the problem writer _thought_ it should mean and we answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You may write

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} {\left( {2 - x} \right)^{\tan \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}x} \right)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} {e^{\tan \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}x} \right)\ln \left( {2 - x} \right)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} {e^{\frac{{\ln \left( {2 - x} \right)}}{{\cot \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}x} \right)}}}} = {e^{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{{\ln \left( {2 - x} \right)}}{{\cot \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}x} \right)}}}}$$

So lets concentrate on the following limit

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{{\ln \left( {2 - x} \right)}}{{\cot \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}x} \right)}}$$

You may use the **Hopital** rule to get

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{{\ln \left( {2 - x} \right)}}{{\cot \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}x} \right)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{{\frac{{ - 1}}{{2 - x}}}}{{ - \left( {1 + {{\cot }^2}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2}x} \right)} \right)\frac{\pi }{2}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{{\left( {2 - x} \right)\left( {1 + {{\cot }^2}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2}x} \right)} \right)\frac{\pi }{2}}} = \frac{2}{\pi }$$

So the final answer is

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} {\left( {2 - x} \right)^{\tan \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}x} \right)}} = {e^{\frac{2}{\pi }}}$$

and we are done.

Comment: After applying L'Hopital's rule, you should obtain $\frac1{x-2}$ in the numerator, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, there is a error which doesn't change the result! :D Corrected. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: I was just sleepy when writing this down.

Answer (score 1):

If we take the log of this function:
$$lim_{x\rightarrow 1} ln(2-x)^{tan\frac{\pi}{2}x} = lim_{x\rightarrow 1} tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)ln(2-x)$$
$$= lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{ln(2-x)}{cot(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}$$
By L'Hopitals rule:
$$= lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{\frac{-1}{2-x}}{{-csc^2(\frac{\pi}{2}x)*\frac{\pi}{2}}}$$
$$= \frac{\frac{-1}{2-1}}{{-csc^2(\frac{\pi}{2})*\frac{\pi}{2}}}$$
$$= \frac{2}{\pi}$$
But his was the log of our function, so if we raise it to the power e the answer is:
$$lim_{x\rightarrow 1} (2-x)^{tan\frac{\pi}{2}x} = e^{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try taking logs, interchanging the limit with the log (this can be done since $\log x$ is a continuous function for $x>0$) and then it may become more obvious.

In other words, let $L=\lim_{x\to1}(2-x)^{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)}$ and then take logs of both sides.

To get you started, I have

$\log L = \log\lim_{x\to1}\left[(2-x)^{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)}\right] = \lim_{x\to1}\log\left[(2-x)^{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)}\right]$.

See if you can use limit and log laws to get something plausible.